# Returning string as text

Tags: vba, excel

I have a very simple code and my is problem is that I want to return a string in different circumstances based on ElseIf but somehow it does not work at all.

If the score is 6 in cell A1 then, the code should return specific text in the cell next to ("Excellent") etc. The code does not want to return the text at all. Can somebody tell me why?

```
Sub ElseIf_ex()

    Dim score As Integer, score_comment As String

    note = Range("A1").Value
    score_comment = Range("B1").Value

    If note = 6 Then
        score_comment = "Excellent"
    ElseIf note = 5 Then
        score_comment = " Good"
    ElseIf note = 4 Then
        score_comment = "Satisfactory"
    Else
        score_comment = "Zero"
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: You need to write the value of `score_comment` back to the cell ;)

Comment: or make score_comment a range `Dim Score_Comment as Range` and set the variable to that object: `Set Score_Comment = Range("B1")`

Comment: Also want to point out that the line `score_comment = Range("B1").Value` is not necessary when the solution is considered since no matter what you are overwriting `score_comment`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to assign `score_comment` back to some cell, otherwise your code might work, but not output anything. You missed to add something like

```
Range("B1").Value=score_comment
```

just before the `End Sub` line.